# How do I stop the axis line from covering over my edge?

Tags: modeling, axis

This one has been driving me crazy or a long time. I have tried every logical setting I can think of, but it will not switch off. I have even turned off every setting in viewport overlays but the line still shows, blocking the edge I want to drag up. Isn't the z axis line a viewport overlay?

[image]
Here are the edges I am tring to drag out by eye.

[image: This is what obliterates the edge]
The axis point hides the edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to <kbd>Kbd</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> switch to Vertex Mode:

[image]

At least, then, you get feedback on the edge's end-position.

(There's also the <kbd>F9</kbd> Adjust Last Operation panel, for tweaking from any viewpoint.)

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful